# What is the opposite of the method abort() in jquery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a video sharing website similar to youtube. So when you upload a video in youtube it stops at 95% then you have to fill out the required input fields.

How will I be able to stop the ajax request then continue it? If the user fills out the title and description then click the button upload, the ajax request will continue

This is my ajax code so far:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var video = $(this).prop('files')[0];
formData.append('video', video);
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;

                $('.video_progress_bar').css('width',`${Math.round(percentComplete * 100)}%`);
                $('.video_progress_bar').text(`${Math.round(percentComplete * 100)}%`);

                if($('.video_progress_bar').text() == '100%'){
                    $('.video_progress_bar').text("Video Uploaded");
                }
            }
       }, false);

       return xhr;
   },
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

I tried setting the ajax to a variable and use the abort method but how will I be able to let the request continue once the user fills out the required input fields?

By the way `this` is referring to the change of the file input, I didn't include that as it doesn't have relevency to the question

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to pause an AJAX request. Once it's out there, the best you can do is abort to tell the app to stop caring about the request's progress/response.

What about the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)?

[resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js) might be helpful as well.